# Retaliation to being spat in the face

Tags: england-and-wales, assault

I understand the spitting at someone intentionally in the UK is an act of assault; my question is more in the relation to the acceptable forms of retaliation, whether throwing a punch for example would be deemed as reasonable or whether this would then qualify as an assault itself but on your part. What is the best way for a member of public to respond to this form of assault, being under UK (or EU) law. Any response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an "acceptable" form of revenge.

Answer (score 2):

### You are allowed to respond to a *threat* with *reasonable* force

**You are not allowed to *retaliate*.**

A *past* assault does not allow the use of force: an *immenant* one does.

Technically, someone *threatening* to spit on you is assault, them actually doing so is battery. Striking someone in response to being spat on is itself battery.

Comment: Couldn't spitting be interpreted as a non-verbal threat of further violence?